# getting java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user exception when connecting to remote mysql database

Tags: mysql, jdbc

im trying to connect to a remote mysql database using jdbc connection. but im getting

java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user this exception when run the java class. But i can connect to this database using mysql query browser or mysql command. i replaced the jdbc driver with previous versions, but still im getting this error. I only have read only access to the remote database. please help me to solve this.

> try {
>         // This will load the MySQL driver, each DB has its own driver
>         Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
>         // Setup the connection with the DB
>
> ```
>   connect = DriverManager
>       .getConnection("jdbc:mysql://myremotehost/remotedatabase?user=username&password=password");
>
>   // Statements allow to issue SQL queries to the database
>   statement = connect.createStatement();
>   // Result set get the result of the SQL query
>   resultSet = statement
>       .executeQuery("select * from mytable limit 10");
>   writeResultSet(resultSet);
>
> } catch (Exception e) {
>   throw e;
> } finally {
>   close();
> }
> ```

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that you are providing right password ?

Comment: yes im sure, because i use same password and username when i tried through query browser.

Comment: Your password doesn't contain any of the following characters I hope? `?&=\/`

Comment: my password contains symbols, is that a problem?

Comment: thanks Mr47, this error comes because password contains & symbol.

Answer (score 1):

hi i found the solution to this issue. this error comes because password contains & symbol. we use & symbol in the jdbc connection string as a seperator.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have supplied correct username and password, it just means that the user has no enough privilege to access the server remotely.

Try the following by creating a new user used to access you application to the server remotely,

```
CREATE USER 'newUser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'newPass123';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'newUser'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

now, use `newUser` and `newPass123` to connect remotely.

- [Adding User Accounts](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/adding-users.html)
- [How to Allow MySQL Client to Connect to Remote MySQL server](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/08/allow-mysql-client-connection/)

Comment: thanks for your reply,the remote server provider only provide read only access to me. but if i dont have enough privilege to access the remote server, so how come i can access it through mysql query browser and i can also query through it. Do you know the reason for this? .

Comment: you can't do anything if the account you are using is for `read-only` access only.

Comment: i just want to execute select statement. i think its possible to execute select statement under read only access. isn't it?

Comment: yes, if the account you are using has privilege to access via remote `%`.

Comment: yes i think i have the privilege, thats why i can connect it through command line/query browser. my problem is why cant i make jdbc connection if i can connect in that way.

Comment: when you connect through query browser, where is the server located? in your pc or remote?

Comment: hi, i also can connect to this database using php script, but still i cannot connect through java jdbc call